# How would I write a program that makes a pattern (like the one below) based on height and width?

Tags: python

The program should design a "digital tile" based on a user-entered name and tile height. The tile width is 3 times the length of the name the user entered.

I honestly have no idea what sort of formula I would use to get the diamond pattern with all the dashes on the sides. Can anyone help me?

Output examples are as follows:

```
Name: Tommy
Tile height: 5

------+|+------
---+|++|++|+---
-----TOMMY-----
---+|++|++|+---
------+|+------


Name: Julia
Tile height: 13

------------------+|+------------------
---------------+|++|++|+---------------
------------+|++|++|++|++|+------------
---------+|++|++|++|++|++|++|+---------
------+|++|++|++|++|++|++|++|++|+------
---+|++|++|++|++|++|++|++|++|++|++|+---
-----------------JULIA-----------------
---+|++|++|++|++|++|++|++|++|++|++|+---
------+|++|++|++|++|++|++|++|++|+------
---------+|++|++|++|++|++|++|+---------
------------+|++|++|++|++|+------------
---------------+|++|++|+---------------
------------------+|+------------------
```

I know generally how to write the program and to make it work, I just have no idea how to get the tile pattern using some sort of incremental code or something. I also don't know how to get it to register that it has reached the middle line and should print the name.

Comment: Can you show the program you are able to write that comes closest to what you want to achieve?

Comment: Two things: what should be the pattern if the name has an **even** length? And doesn't your second example contradict the rule 'width = 3 * name_length' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that the tiles are accurate, and your description is incomplete/inaccurate, as the second tile definitely longer than "3 times the length of the name the user entered".

The rules I see are actually the following:

1. Rows not containing names are built of two types of three character long sections: "---" and "+|+".
2. Top row contains one "+|+" in the middle, and each following row will replace two "---" sections with the same string (one in each direction).
3. The rows before the name will still have two "---" sections (one on each side).
4. Row length equals 3 * tile height.
5. I am implicitly  assuming only odd numbers are accepted as height, due to the structure seen in your examples.

```
import math

height = 9
length = height * 3

# calculating the number of tile rows above and below the name row
outside_rows = math.floor(height/2)

# building rows above the name row
for n in range(0,outside_rows):
    tile_sections = 2 * n + 1
    background_length = int((length - tile_sections * 3) / 2)
    print("-" * background_length, "+|+" * tile_sections, "-" * background_length, sep='')

# you can print your named row here
print("")

# building rows below the name row
for n in range(outside_rows-1, -1, -1):
    tile_sections = 2 * n + 1
    background_length = int((length - tile_sections * 3) / 2)
    print("-" * background_length, "+|+" * tile_sections, "-" * background_length, sep='')
```

Output:

```
------------+|+------------
---------+|++|++|+---------
------+|++|++|++|++|+------
---+|++|++|++|++|++|++|+---

---+|++|++|++|++|++|++|+---
------+|++|++|++|++|+------
---------+|++|++|+---------
------------+|+------------
```

Comment: Nice enough, but there's an (I assume) unwanted space between --- and +|+ .

Comment: Indeed. Now fixed. Thanks for noting.